# If $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, show that $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ if $n x \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

For this question would I be correct in stating the following

If $n$ is a positive integer and $n x$ is a rational number then $n x = n (a / b)$.

Simplifying this = $x = (a / b)$ so $x$ must also be a rational number.

I'm not entirely sure if making the first claim is correct.

Comment: Well, your conclusion is right...not sure about your argument.  You appear to start from the assumption that $x$ is rational, which of course you don't know at the start of the proof.  I'd say:    If $nx=\frac rs$ then $x=\frac {r}{ns}$.

Comment: That makes more sense thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct argument is as follows: $nx=\frac a b$ with $a,b$ intergers, $b \neq 0$. Hence $x= \frac {a} {nb}$ which is rational. It is not logical to assume that $nx=n\frac a b$.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This argument is not valid.

If $nx$ is rational then $nx = \frac ab$ for integers $a,b$.

The only way that $nx = n \frac ab$ would be if $x = \frac ab$ which is what you are trying to prove.

You are assuming what you are trying to prove.  That is a no-no and is always wrong.

....

But if you start with $nx =\frac ab$ then the proof pretty much writes itself.  $x = \frac a{bn}$ and so....